# PHP using vars inside a function without pasing param

Tags: php

In the following code; is there a way to use the vars inside the function without having to pass them as params?

```
$var1 = 'test';
$var2 = 'another';

function testing(){
    print $var1;
}
```

I read up on the php global's but wasn't sure if it was a good idea.

I have an ajax call that gets about 25 vars and replaces the tags in the body of an email where the placeholders are.

The sendEmail piece is in a function and needs access to the outside vars to be able to replace the content.

Without having a `function(){}` with 25 vars in it, is there another way to acomplish this?

**UPDATE**

Here is a sample snippet of my code; the reason why I am trying to do this.

http://pastebin.com/8qYsLg5T

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use global variables, except possibly for configuration and for shared resources (like database connections).  If you need to pass 25 things in to a function then perhaps what you need is a class with a method, where you can set the properties of the object and then invoke the method (which then gets implicit access to these properties through `$this`).

Comment: If you already have the data packaged neatly inside an object (`$fetchData`), why not just pass in that object? You could even just pass in `$fetchData->data` and then inside the function `$data->whatever`.

Comment: What was there to downvote the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as the answer above make vars global.Kinda bad practice and you will end up overwriting them if you re use them and it makes them available for attacks. 
What you should be doing(is writing them out) but if that is to much then making the vars an array  then passing them as an array. Chances are your getting the data in an array form.

```
        $vars = array(
        'varname1' => 'var_value1',
        'varname2' => 'var_value2',
        'varname3' => 'var_value3',
        );
do_stuff_with_vars($vars);
```

You could quickly create an array as someone else here suggested by using compact.
`compact(var,var2,etc);`

Your function should look something like

```
function do_stuff_with_vars($array){
        //do stuff with array["varnameX"]
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it's not clear what keys from the array the function is going to use.

Comment: @JuanMendes how does defining a class tell you what properties the function is going to use? The function doesn't have to use them just because they are defined.

Comment: @JuanMaendes, While that is true, appropriate function naming and labeled documentation can and will make it clear. The function also does not have to use every set of data in this way. It's lazy, but so is OP. Otherwise he'd type out the 25 vars.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var1 = 'test';
$var2 = 'another';

function testing(){
    global $var1;
    print $var1;
}
```

Comment: variables defined outside of the function scope are already global. So the global keyword when defining `$var1` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [compact()](https://www.php.net/compact) to put all of the variables in an array, then pass that to your function.

```
<?php
$data = compact($var1, $var2, $var3, $var4);
testing($data);

function testing($data) {
  print $data['var1'];
  print $data['var2'];
  // Or, if you don't want to use an array here, use extract() to do the
  // opposite of compact():
  extract($data);
  print $var3;
  print $var4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_array = array(
   'element1' => $var1,
   'element2' => $var2
);

function testing($my_array){
    print $my_array['element1'];
    // or use foreach()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using oop

```
class A {
   public $var = 'test';
   public $var2;

   public function test(){
     print $this->var;
   } 

}

 $a = new A();
 $a->test();
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use globals, use OOP. You could create a class as a holder for the 25 parameters and use them from your `send` function

```
class MyMail {
    public $user;
    public $subject;
    public $body;  

    public function send() {
        // do the send
        mail($this->user, $this->subject, ...);
    }
}

$mailSender = new MyMail();
$mailSender->user = 'a@b.com';
$mailSender->subject = 'Hello';
$mailSender->send();
```